# Android view partly on top of scrollable active listview

Tags: android, listview

I'm creating a music player where I have a listview-activity to choose songs from. Whenever I choose a song I need a smaller view to pop-up on the bottom of the screen, on top of the listview, just like edit-text when the keyboard pops-up.
But I also want to still be able to scroll the listview(when the song is playing) without the smaller view disappearing from the screen.
The smaller view will contain buttons for the player.
Is this possible?
If so, what is the best way to do this?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of doing this could be to reserve as space for the smaller view and then set it's visibility to invisible, then when the song is picked set it's visibility to visible `layoutelement.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`
where your layout element is the piece who's visibility you are changing.

Since your whole layout is within a scroll view when your layout visibility is set to visible the other components of your layout will be pushed below and you'll be able to scroll through it all.

Comment: This sounds good. How do I design the player? Should I do that in a separate xml-file and then, if possible, import it to the main-layout?